# Using .slideToggle() (or any other jQuery method) how can I get a div to overlap another once button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So what I have is a `<section>` that is hidden on the page, and when a user clicks "Get Started" that `<section>` will appear over the hero container `<div>` at the top or the spotlight `<section>` at the bottom depending on where Get Started was clicked. I figured out how to get the slideToggle to work, I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to cover another `<div>`.

Visually speaking, it's like you're pulling a blanket over your bed. the blanket being the hidden `<section>` and the bed being the Get Started `<div>`

```js
$("#hideshow").click(function() {
  $("#IFEstream").slideToggle(1000);
});

$("#hideshow2").click(function() {
  $("#IFEstream").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Test_IFE_Splash_wrapper -->
<!-- mIFE directory -->

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CCS Logo</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-sm visible-xs">
      <li><a href="#">DONATE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Francais</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DONATE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- /Navbar -->

<!--Hero Container-->
<!-- hero image -->
<!-- Get started top button -->
<!-- Get inspired, will link to spotlight sectional -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3">Hero Image</h1>
    <p>Your journey against cancer starts here.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" id="hideshow">Get Started</a>  <a class="btn btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Get Inspired</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/Hero Container-->

<!-- 3 Steps-->
<section style="background-color: #0066CC;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Decide</h2>
          <p>Pick an activity that is right for you - from donating your birthday to hosting a board game night for friends and family, there are countless ways to contribute. And just like that, you&#8217;ll be part of our Cancer Fighter community!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Fundraise</h2>
          <p>We want to set you up for success! Once you&#8217;re registered, you will have access to all of our tips and tricks to make sure you reach your fundraising goal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Celebrate</h2>
          <p>Give yourself a pat on the back and feel great knowing that you&#8217;ve just done something profound to help the 196,900 Canadians who will be diagnosed with cancer this year alone.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /Sectional Blue Background -->

<!-- IFE Stream -->
<!-- section hidden until Get Started clicked, will cover above or below -->
<!-- RFI Form -->
<section id="IFEstream" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h1>ICON</h1>
          <h3>CUT</h3>
          <p>Cut it, shave it, dye it, grow it or braid it. Get started with your hair-raising fundraiser.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">START MY FUNDRAISER</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h1>ICON</h1>
          <h3>SWEAT</h3>
          <p>Run, walk, swim, bike or paddle your way to a successful fundraising event.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">START MY FUNDRAISER</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h1>ICON</h1>
          <h3>My idea</h3>
          <p>Already have your own idea? Or something you love to do? Turn your hobby into a meaningful fundraiser.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">START MY FUNDRAISER</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class='text-muted'>REGISTER THROUGH YOUR LOCAL COMMUNITY OFFICE</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /IFE Stream -->


<!-- Spotlight -->
<section id="spotlight">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Xanthe</h3>
          <p>Inspired by the movie Tangled, Xanthe's goal was to grow her hair down to her ankles - but now wants to help cancer patients by donating her hair and raising funds to support the fight against cancer. Xanthe raised over $1,000 in honour of her
            cousin who is battling leukemia.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Team Gary</h3>
          <p>Team Gary recently ran in the Mississauga Marathon to support their Grandfather, Father and Family member Gary who is currently fighting liver cancer. The team of 13 raised an incredible $4,455 in the fight against cancer. Way to go Team Gary!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Johnny Blonde Kitchen</h3>
          <p>This year they were very excited to be opening a storefront location. They raised $1,300 by fundraising online, and donating 10% of sales from opening day. In addition to fundraising, Jonny cut off his famous locks and donated several inches
            to Locks Of Love. We are so excited to have them be a part of our CCS family!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Brevitas Consulting</h3>
          <p>Brevitas Consulting takes on Breast Cancer Awareness Month each October with a walk-a-thon held one weekend during October bringing together their team in a fun, uplifting event. Thank you Brevitas!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Irudaya</h3>
          <p>These talented young women created and executed a two hour dance production; Journey: A Glimpse Into Tamil Cinema. With the Society being one of their charities of choice, these dancers raised $10,000 for the fight against cancer! Amazing work!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
          <h3>Maureen Parent</h3>
          <p>Maureen is a breast cancer survivor who is dedicate to raising funds for cancer research. In 10 years she has raised over $85,000 with an annual pasta dinner and has her sights set on raising $1,000,000 for the fight against breast cancer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>Be a cancer fighter &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="hideshow2">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /Sectional White Background -->

<!-- Footer -->
<!--Province Locator, main site, contact, policy, blackbaud -->
<footer class="footer" style="background-color: #0066CC;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mUFE/2016/one/img/CCS_EnUni_Reversed_4C_EPS.png" width="200" height="80" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <a href="#">Province</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Cancer.ca</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/IFE_ON/IFE_Splash_Page_Code/img/reskin/logo_blackbaud.png" width="80" height="40" />
            </a>
            <br>
            <p class="text-muted text-right">2016 Canadian Cancer Society All rights reserved. Registered charity: 118829803 RR 0001</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I tried googling but I guess I'm not wording my question right because I can't find it. I know I've seen it before so it has been done.

Appreciate everyone's time and thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa why was jquery 3.1.1 changed to 2.1.1?

Comment: All your libraries depends on JQuery & you have included the JQuery at the very end, so your snippet was not actually working if you didn't notice. moved it up. Version changed to what you had(3.1.1)

Comment: On which div do you want it to overlap ? currently its pushing the spotlight div when appearing.

Comment: There are two Get start buttons, so the one at the top is in the hero container, so for the top `<div class="jumbotron">` and the bottom `<section id="spotlight">` depending one which one is clicked, overlap that one

Comment: Getting close, though I noticed the slide section for the top "Get Started" is much taller than the jumbotron section, so it does overlap but the content is overflowing to the below section as well.How do you want this to behave ?

Comment: Oh i see, well Ideally I'd like it to fit above the the 3 steps (Decide, Fundraise, Celebrate) so if it pushes it down a bit that would be perfectly fine! thanks for your help Nikhil!

Comment: I am currently sliding the hide/show section just below the Get Started section & inside the jumbotron itself - If i overlap it on top of Get Started section, how would you click "GetStarted" again to hide it ? Thats fine ?

Comment: Well actually, after learning how to overlap the section on to the Get Started area I was going to figure out how to add a x close button (a little x in the corner) to close the slider so that the user can see the Get Started div again

Comment: Awesome, I like this approach - I have updated my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ENLaxq) already to include a close icon & making it work as you wanted. have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to you code to get it working (explanation below)

have a look - [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ENLaxq)

I'm sure its not exactly what you are looking for but its very close & can be refactored.

**Explanation:**

First & foremost, I think you need to understand your HTML structure. If you need the section to be hidden/shown(toggled) in **2 different places** then you MUST have 2 sections in the HTML as well. basically you should have 2 `IFStream` sections. Basically you cannot dynamically move the entire section from top to bottom when you toggle button & then show it - This is not possible unless you use really dirty method which I do not recommend.

**Solution:**

I however have used 2 sections(1 placed below top Get Started inside jumbotron & the other below bottom Get Started), then I am toggling them **individually** which is important.

**Updated:**

When Get Started is clicked, the appropriate section is shown(hiding the Get Started section) - overlaps & then a "X" icon is given to toggle it back.

Let me know what needs to be changed in the Codepen link above

Comment: oh man that is beautiful! thank you Nikhil, exactly what I'm looking for! and thank you for the clear explanation, makes sense to have two sections. And it seems to be working in a Mobile view too! so cool haha thanks again Nikhil!

Comment: No worries .. Cheers!